# Find out the position of the line in file using spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, rdd

I have a seq like below:

```
 val data = Seq("banagalore",
    "Delhi.","","","","Mubmai","Kolkata","Jammu$Kashmir")
  val rddData = ss.sparkContext.parallelize(data,3)
  val output = rddData.flatMap(_.split(" "))
```

So, my requirement is to print the blelow O/P
1.(word,Position of the word in the  sequence, number of characters in sequence)

```
Eg:For Mumbai it will print("Mumbai",5,6)
```

5=Position of the word Mumbai in Sequence
6=Number of characters in word "Mumbai"

```
Also,

    O/p 2:Also I have to find out below:

        (word,Position of the word in the  sequence, Word with Maximum elements)
        (word,Position of the word in the  sequence,  Word with Minimum  characters
```

Comment: not sure where the 9 is coming from

Comment: Hi @Elinda sorry ,it is not 9. It is 5.  5-Position Of Word Mumbai in the sequence  and 6=Number of characters in "Mumbai Word"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the zipWithIndex method that gives the position of the item in the RDD. You can apply a filter on the one you need after setting the zipWithIndex and you will get what you want

```
 val data = Seq("banagalore",
    "Delhi.","","","","Mubmai","Kolkata","Jammu$Kashmir")
  val rddData = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data,3)

val a = rddData.zipWithIndex.map(a => (a._1, a._2, a._1.length())).filter(v => v._1 == "Mubmai").take(2)

println(a(0))
```

The output will be

```
(Mubmai,5,6)
```

I am using the take(2) to capture the first two rows of the RDD, but as there is only one (as I filtered on Mubmai) it prints only one (that's why I am doing the println(a(0)).

Hope this helps